# Python DataFrames has a concat or append problem

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

My major is not programming or coding. But there's something to do with Python at work, and I have to do it. I studied alone for a month and made this code, but I'd like to change it to the right loop structure. How can I do it?

- Condition 1. df and mark changes 0 ~ 900.(not 0 ~ 10)
- Condition 2. Access keys can only be called 500 times a day, so I hope you don't try too much.

Additional question: how should I code if I receive data in the form of XML?

```
import urllib.request
import json
import pandas as pd
import datetime

Host = "https://oapi.saramin.co.kr/job-search?access-key=L8ILhlpIElsdz7BvhWQxcON3g8WBCSRyPTBEY7qlitt5ksdVBV6"
headers = { Host: "oapi.saramin.co.kr", "Accept": "application/json"}

for i in range(0, 10) :
    pages = i + 1
    url = Host + "&start=" + str(pages) + "&count=110"
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    json_str = response.read().decode("utf-8")
    json_object = json.loads(json_str)
    globals()['mark{}'.format(i)] = pd.json_normalize(json_object['jobs']['job'])

df0=pd.DataFrame(mark0)
df1=pd.DataFrame(mark1)
df2=pd.DataFrame(mark2)
df3=pd.DataFrame(mark3)
df4=pd.DataFrame(mark4)
df5=pd.DataFrame(mark5)
df6=pd.DataFrame(mark6)
df7=pd.DataFrame(mark7)
df8=pd.DataFrame(mark8)
df9=pd.DataFrame(mark9)

df_all = pd.concat([df0, df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8, df9])

today_string = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%y.%m.%d_%Hh%Mm%Ss')
df_all.to_excel('Saramin_Raw_Data(' + today_string + ').xlsx')
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Does your code throw any errors? Is it giving incorrect output?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take a look at [tour] page and [ask] question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code:-

```
import urllib.request
import json
import pandas as pd
import datetime

Host = "https://oapi.saramin.co.kr/job-search?access-key=L8ILhlpIElsdz7BvhWQxcON3g8WBCSRyPTBEY7qlitt5ksdVBV6"
headers = { Host: "oapi.saramin.co.kr", "Accept": "application/json"}

df_list = list()
NUM_FILES = 3
for i in range(0, NUM_FILES+1) :
    pages = i + 1
    url = Host + "&start=" + str(pages) + "&count=110"
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    json_str = response.read().decode("utf-8")
    json_object = json.loads(json_str)
    mark = pd.json_normalize(json_object['jobs']['job'])
    df = pd.DataFrame(mark)
    df_list.append(df)

df_all = pd.concat(df_list)

today_string = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%y.%m.%d_%Hh%Mm%Ss')
df_all.to_excel('Saramin_Raw_Data(' + today_string + ').xlsx')
```

You have to set the value of `NUM_FILES = 900`

I hope this helps!!

Regarding your additional question you can follow this nice medium article:-
https://medium.com/@robertopreste/from-xml-to-pandas-dataframes-9292980b1c1c